# XPath child::* vs child::node()

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm working with an XSLT transformation, and I found an interesting question that I couldn't answer:

**What's the difference between `child::*` and `child::node()`
?**

I want to create a condition in which I delimit the quantity of children elements to 1, in this case:

```
<xsl:if test="parent[count(child::*) eq 1])">
```

vs

```
<xsl:if test="parent[count(child::node()) eq 1])">
```

What would be the difference?

Comment: The spec is online so try reading https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#node-tests and tell us which parts you don't understand.

Comment: Excellent question!  There are subtle differences that escape many casual users of XPath.  See [**my answer below**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46123494/290085) for details.

Comment: Where did you look for an answer to this question before asking here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand the difference between `child::*` and `child::node()` in XPath, understand not only the difference between the `*` and `node()` node tests, but also the concept of the [***principal node type***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests) of an axis...

### Principal Node Type

**Rule:** If an axis can contain elements, then its **principal node type** is `element`; otherwise, it's the node type that the axis can contain.  (For example, the **principal node type** of `attribute` axis is `attribute` because it can only contain attributes.)

The `child` axis can contain elements, so the **principal node type** of the child axis is `element`.

### Node Tests per Axis

Therefore, the difference between `child::*` and `child::node()` is that

- the `*` node test on the `child` axis succeeds for all **child *elements*** of the
  context node, because the `*` node test succeeds for *all nodes of the principal node type* (`element`, here) whereas
- the `node()` node test succeeds for all **child *nodes*** of the
  context node, because the `node()` node test succeeds for *all nodes types*.  However, note that not all nodes types can be on the `child` axis. Here are the seven types of nodes and whether they can appear on the child axis:

  - *root*: No, the root is the child of no other node, by definition.
  - *element*: Yes
  - *text*: Yes
  - *attribute*: No, attributes have their own axis.
  - *namespace*: No, namespaces have their own axis.
  - *processing instruction*: Yes
  - *comment*: Yes

Therefore, `child::*` matches all *element* children of the context node, and `child::node()` matches all all *element, text, and processing instruction* children of the context node.

Comment: Good answer.  This difference is also documented by [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).

Answer (score 3):

> What's the difference between child::* and child::node().

To quote from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns):

- `*` matches any element
- `node()` matches any node other than an attribute node and the root node

So `child::*` matches only child elements and 
`child::node()` matches any child nodes except attributes and the root node. These can be five of the seven node types: elements, comments, text and namespace nodes and processing instructions ([see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model)).

Comment: Since when is CDATA a node type?! And since when is w3schools a reference?! There are exactly seven types of node listed in the [XPath specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model): root, element, text, attribute, namespace, processing instruction and comment.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thanks for correcting me. I was mistaken with the CDATA by some past coding experiences and didn't had it in mind correctly.

Comment: This is basically correct (+1), but the full answer is a little more subtle than can fit in a comment, so I've [**added a new answer to explain**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46123494/290085).  (It's not that `*` as a node test can only match elements, and it's not that `node()` as a node test cannot match attributes; it's their position on the `child` axis that implicitly adds these restrictions.  See my answer for further details.)